# Sum of sum of column over()

Tags: t-sql

I'm basically trying to understand what the following query would return(and most importantly why):

```
 SELECT SUM(SUM(column)) OVER() FROM table
```

In practice it returns one row with a sum which is actually the sum of the column over the whole result-set of the table. I don't get why we get this result though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These will return the same value. Having them together like this is redundant. The innermost SUM will sum all row values, so the outermost SUM has nothing left to sum. You can look at the query plan and you will see that one of the aggregations is empty.

```
SELECT SUM(SUM(column)) OVER() FROM table

SELECT SUM(column) FROM table
```

Comment: That's what I thought also... Do you have any idea why would this be preferred though? Some weird extreme case? It's just that I found it used somewhere frequently and it baffles me why

Comment: Copy-paste perhaps, or a quickfix/bad edit of an older more complex expression.

Comment: I accept the answer as correct as you ARE correct. Apparently this segment was added in generated statement which in the end had a "GROUP BY" clause. That of course changes everything since the result is that we get the full sum of ALL results in each row even though they are grouped by something